# Extract consecutive non-null numbers with their respective starting and ending indexes from a list?

Tags: c#, .net

say, if I have a `List<double?>` that looks like `null, null, 2, 3, 4, null, null, 3, 3, null` and I want to extract consecutive non null numbers with their respective starting and ending indexes in relation to the main list - how do I do that? the result should be a list with two objects, `{ startIndex = 2, endIndex = 4, list = [ 2, 3, 4 ] }` and `{ startIndex = 7, endIndex = 8, list = [ 3, 3 ] }`

i'm trying to use this code but it doesn't work

`refinedList` is my data list. i need `xBegin` and `xEnd` and i should calculate them based on bounds and pass the data to `DataPointsToLine` method - this is my ultimate goal. i simplified and generalized the case, above.

```
var tempList = new List<double>();
double xBegin = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < refinedList.Count; i++)
{
    if (refinedList[i].HasValue)
    {
        if (i > 0)
            if (!refinedList[i - 1].HasValue)
            {
                xBegin = rect.Width * ((nfloat)i / (data.Count - 1));
            }
        tempList.Add(refinedList[i].Value);
    }
    else
    {
        if (i > 0)
            if (refinedList[i - 1].HasValue)
            {
                result.Add(DataPointsToLine(tempList, rect.Height, xBegin, rect.Width * ((nfloat)(i - 1) / (data.Count - 1))));
                tempList = new List<double>();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: how this code related to your problem?

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* - what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: this wont compile ` if (refinedList[i - 1].HasValue ||)`

Comment: Why are you using rects?  What type is `nfloat`?

Comment: see the edit. @DanField this is irrelevant.

Comment: is this an interview question?

Comment: Please look at [MCVE]....

Comment: @celerno no it isn't

Comment: If you're trying to extract non-null values, don't put them in your list. Why are they there at all?

Comment: @DourHighArch it's a result of an API call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My version [DotNetFiddle.Net Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lkOUeh):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<Double?> { null, null, 2, 3, 4, null, null, 3, 3, null };
        var groupLists = new List<GroupList>();
        GroupList currentGroupList = null;

        for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (list.ElementAt(i).HasValue)
            {
                if (currentGroupList == null)
                {
                    currentGroupList = new GroupList();
                    currentGroupList.Start = i;
                    groupLists.Add(currentGroupList);
                }
                currentGroupList.Items.Add(list.ElementAt(i).Value);
            }
            else
            {
                if (currentGroupList != null)
                {
                    currentGroupList.End = i -1;
                }
                currentGroupList = null;
            }
        }
        if (currentGroupList != null)
        {
            currentGroupList.End = list.Count -1;
        }



        foreach(var groupList in groupLists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} [{2}]", groupList.Start, groupList.End, string.Join(",",groupList.Items.ToArray()));
        }
    }

    public class GroupList
    {
        public GroupList()
        {
            Items = new List<Double>();
        }

        public int Start { get; set; }
        public int End { get; set; }
        public List<Double> Items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2 4 [2,3,4]
7 8 [3,3]
```

Comment: Good catch, I'll fix that now.

Answer (score 2):

How about this class to encapsulate the results:

```
public sealed class Sublist
{
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int End   { get; set; }

    public List<double> Numbers { get; set; }

    public Sublist(int start, int end, List<double> numbers)
    {
        Start   = start;
        End     = end;
        Numbers = numbers;
    }
}
```

You can generate the sublists like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<Sublist> FindNonNullRanges(List<double?> numbers)
{
    int start = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; ++i)
    {
        if (!numbers[i].HasValue)
        {
            if (start >= 0)
            {
                yield return new Sublist(
                    start,
                    i - 1,
                    numbers.Skip(start).Take(i - start).Cast<double>().ToList());
            }

            start = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (start < 0)
                start = i;
        }
    }

    if (start >= 0)
    {
        yield return new Sublist(
            start,
            numbers.Count-1,
            numbers.Skip(start).Take(numbers.Count - start).Cast<double>().ToList());
    }
}
```

And some test code:

```
static void Main()
{
    List<double?> test = new List<double?>
    {
        null, null, 2, 3, 4, null, null, 3, 3, null
    };

    foreach (var sublist in FindNonNullRanges(test))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"From {sublist.Start} to {sublist.End} = [{string.Join(", ", sublist.Numbers)}]");
    }
}
```

This outputs the following:

> From 2 to 4 = [2, 3, 4]
>
> From 7 to 8 = [3, 3]

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<refinedList.Count;i++){
        if(refinedList[i].HasValue)
       {
          //setup start index
          while(refinedList[i].HasValue && i<refinedList.Count)
           //add items to list
          i++;
       }
        //Setup end index
}
```

Comment: Hope this helps you, I'm on a mobile. Difficult to work.